# How to find a single entry in a Python dictionary rather than a whole line?

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to to return a single entry from a dictionary (or similar). For example I have a dictionary that looks something like this:

```
    StockTable = {
        "Code 1": ["Description 1", 100, 1.25],
        "Code 2": ["Description 2", 200, 2.25],
    }
```

For reference the columns are Code / Description / Price / Weight

I want to be able to use single aspects of that data (say description), in multiple ways, elsewhere; for example:

```
    TreeView.insert("", END, values= (Value1, StockTable["Code1"], Value3))
```

In the above I only want to carry over the Description. Is there a way of indexing a cell within a dictionary and returning a single value?

Thanks

Comment: The value is just a [**`list`**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), so you can index it (starting from 0): `StockTable["Code1"][0]`

Comment: @PeterWood is correct. Also, it sounds like you want a data table such as a `pandas.DataFrame` and you want to work with columns of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use a better dictionary.

```
>>> StockTable = {k: dict(zip(('Description', 'Price', 'Weight'), v)) for k, v in StockTable.items()}
>>> StockTable
{'Code 1': {'Description': 'Description 1', 'Price': 100, 'Weight': 1.25}, 'Code 2': {'Description': 'Description 2', 'Price': 200, 'Weight': 2.25}}
>>> StockTable['Code 1']['Description']
'Description 1'
```

... or `pandas`.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(StockTable).T
>>> df
          Description Price Weight
Code 1  Description 1   100   1.25
Code 2  Description 2   200   2.25
>>> df.at['Code 1', 'Description']
'Description 1'
```

Comment: What about [@dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)?

Comment: @PeterWood another valid option